# VB.net - Adding to an ArrayList

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist

This is my first time using `ArrayList`. I have tried to add to `BarcodeArray` (*as an arraylist*) and execution is failing with the error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code is shown below:

```
'Populate the arrays        
BarcodeArray.Add(txt_Barcode.Text)
CategoryArray.Add(cmb_Categories.Text)
TitleArray.Add(txt_Title.Text)
DescriptionArray.Add(txt_Description.Text)
QuantityArray.Add(txt_Quantity.Text)
RRPArray.Add(txt_RRP.Text)
CostArray.Add(txt_Cost.Text)
```

This message appears when **line 2** is executed. How do I add text to an ArrayList from a textbox without getting this error?

Comment: BarcodeArray is nothing. Just initialize it. Dim ar as new ArrayList()

Comment: Just curious what your reason is for needing to maintain a separate ArrayList for each of the different values you list.  From their names, it would seem better suited to something like a `Product` class with the properties of `Barcode`, `Category`, etc.  Then you would populate a `List(Of Product)` which could contain all of those values for each product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue you're having is that you are not instantiating your ArrayLists before using them.  You would need to do something like this to get your code to work:

```
Dim barcodeArray as New ArrayList()
barcodeArray.Add(txt_Barcode.Text)
... etc ...
```

But in your case, I think I would create a new class:

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property Barcode as String
    Public Property Category as String
    Public Property Title as String
    ... etc ...
End Class
```

Then I would use it in code like this:

```
Dim productList as New List(Of Product)()
productList.Add(new Product() With {
    .Barcode = txt_Barcode.Text,
    .Category = cmb_Categories.Text,
    .Title = txt_Title.Text,
    ... etc ...
})
```

This would let you use a single `Product` object rather than separate `ArrayList` objects, which would be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: To add to Aaron's suggestion, I would add an "Public Overrides Function ToString() As String" to the class and set the Return to something like "return me.Title"; something that makes since when added to the list.  It makes debugging much simpler and makes it so you can add the arrayed list to nearly any object and see the desired information.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET, you need to *instantiate* objects before you can call methods on them. Example:

```
Dim a As ArrayList
a.Add(...)           ' Error: object reference `a` has not been set
```

The solution is to initialize the variable with a *new* ArrayList:

```
Dim a As ArrayList

a = New ArrayList()
a.Add(...)
```

or, alternatively:

```
Dim a As New ArrayList()
a.Add(...)
```

BTW, `ArrayList` is an old class that mainly exists for backwards compatibility. When you are starting a new project, use the [generic `List` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead:

```
Dim a As New List(Of String)()
a.Add(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **instantiate** it before you can use. The problem in **line 2** is that it is `null` at that time (`Nothing` in *VB.NET*) since it is not created

Since all the values you want to add to the list has *same type* which is `String` i suggest you use a `List(Of String)` instead of `ArrayList`

Try the following:

```
Dim BarcodeArray as List(Of String) = New List(Of String)( { txt_Barcode.Text } )
Dim CategoryArray as List(Of String) = New List(Of String)( { cmb_Categories.Text } )
' ...
' Same for the other Lists you will need to use
```